# Most occuring contiguous substring - Sliding Window - Python

Tags: python, substring

In practicing python, I've come across the sliding window technique but don't quite understand the implementation. Given a string k and integer N, the code is to loop through, thereby moving the window from left to right. However, the capture of the windowed elements as well as how the window grows is fuzzy to me.

These sliding window questions on Leetcode are similar but do not have the alphabetic aspect.

1. Fruits into baskets : https://leetcode.com/problems/fruit-into-baskets/
2. Longest substring without repeating characters : https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/
3. Longest substring after k replacements : https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-repeating-character-replacement/
4. Permutation in string: https://leetcode.com/problems/permutation-in-string/
5. String anagrams: https://leetcode.com/problems/find-all-anagrams-in-a-string/
6. Average of any contiguous subarray of size k : https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-average-subarray-i/
7. Maximum sum of any contiguous subarray of size k : https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-subarray/
8. Smallest subarray with a given sum : https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-size-subarray-sum/
9. Longest substring with k distinct characters : https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-with-at-most-k-distinct-characters/

Most occurring contiguous sub-string here defined as three letters in growing sequence. For example, for an input string k of 'cdegoxyzcga' and length N of 3, the output would be [cde, xyz].

Comment: Look at the first two letters of the string and record one occurrence of that substring (probably using a dictionary).  Look at the second and third letters and record one occurrence of that substring.  (If the target substring is two different letters, then you can step forward by two letters each time instead of just one.)  At the end, examine your dictionary (or whatever means you used to record the substring occurrences) and find the largest number of occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = {}
input = 2;
inputString = "abrtidyzabfo"

for i in range(0, len(inputString)):
  if i >= input-1:
    current = inputString[i+1-input: i+1]
    if current in result:
      result[current] = result[current] + 1 
    else:
      result[current] = 1
print(result)
```

You can use a dictionary to do tracking of particular substrings that appears or not. This kind of approach is known as the "Sliding Window Algorithm". At this time complexity will be O(n) as you are running the loop once only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Counter` to collect the counts while rolling on the string:

```
s = 'abrtidyzabfo'
n = 2

from collections import Counter
c = Counter(s[i:i+n] for i in range (len(s)-n+1))

out = c.most_common(1)[0][0]
```

Output: `'ab'`

*NB. There might be more than 1 "most frequent" string. To see all:*

```
c = Counter(s[i:i+n] for i in range (len(s)-n+1))

out = []
MAX = 0
for x, i in c.most_common():
    if i > MAX:
        out = [x]
        MAX = i
    elif i == MAX:
        out.append(x)
out
```

Example using `s = "abrtidyzabfody"` as input:

```
['ab', 'dy']
```